# Apex class couldn't be created

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

I am using a sandbox developer edition of salesforce. In Setup, when I search "Apex Class" in quick find box, no results were found. Also the File-->New-->Apex Class option is disabled in developer console window. How could I create a Apex class in salesforce. Also My aim is to create a visualforce page, which loads some external data(through api call) in visualforce page in a table format with custom links. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your user has a limited profile on sandbox and has no access to Apex classes and any other developer options. This case you need to ask someone with Admin rights to provide an access to you. I guess that permission **[Author Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88687/permission-to-write-apex-code)** can help you

Comment: I don't see **Author Apex** permission checkbox in my profile. Can you please locate the exact position of that checkbox? Also, I am currently using the trail version.

Comment: @Muthu it should be under "Administrative Permissions" section. See the link, it contains a screenshot. What do you mean "trail version" is it trial version of some salesforce edition? Or is it developer edition org for trailhead? And who is created the org which you use (some system admin or you)?

Comment: I have attached my administrative permissions screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4JUm.png), and I am the System Administrator here. What I mean by trail version is , I am using a trail developer edition of salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Manage users** > **Profiles** > **System Permissions**

[image]